# I have a question about show/hide function

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a question about show/hide function with divs that have multiple classes

So I have 4 buttons and 4 classes, and I know how to show/hide divs that have only one class...

```
<button id="button1"></button>
<button id="button2"></button>
<button id="button3"></button>
<button id="button4"></button>

<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
```

However, if div has multiple classes:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

following script doesn't work..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
$(".class1").show();
$(".class2").hide();
$(".class3").hide();
$(".class4").hide();
});
$("#button1").click(function(){
$(".class1").hide();
$(".class2").show();
$(".class3").hide();
$(".class4").hide();
});
$("#button3").click(function(){
$(".class1").hide();
$(".class2").hide();
$(".class3").show();
$(".class4").hide();
});
$("#button4").click(function(){
$(".class1").hide();
$(".class2").hide();
$(".class3").hide();
$(".class4").show();
});
</script>
```

Also, can I write it somehow that I don't have to write every div that I want to hide?

```
.hasClass show()
else hide()
```

Because in the future I might have 20 classes or more...

Sorry I am beginner :)

Comment: Minimal working snipped would be nice.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"?  Which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What is that result?  What result was expected?  Why?  It makes no difference how many classes your elements have.  (It might require you to change your logic, but it doesn't change what the `show` and `hide` functions do.)

Comment: Doesn't work - means that If I have a div with multiple classes class="class1 class2 class3", then it takes only the last class, which means only button3 works and makes class3 visible.. Button 1 and 2 doesn't show the element...

Comment: I developed a workaround having separate classes for items with multiple classes - class="class1-class2" and having extra values like $(".class1-class2").show(); - which is very ugly and temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

It is because you the `show` first and then `hide`.
In order for it to work, you should hide all class name selectors and then do a `.show` for the relevant class selector.

A cleaner approach would be create a `hideAll` method and then `.show` for the relevant class selector.

Comment: Wow! this actually seems to work! Thanks!

$("div").hide();
$(".class1").show();

Comment: You're welcome @Hannes. Could you please upvote the answer if it worked for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it think it's every think work ok but you have a syntax error in last
and that who stop everything

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".class1").show();
    $(".class2").hide();
    $(".class3").hide();
    $(".class4").hide();
    });
    $("#button2").click(function(){
    $(".class1").hide();
    $(".class2").show();
    $(".class3").hide();
    $(".class4").hide();
    });
    $("#button3").click(function(){
    $(".class1").hide();
    $(".class2").hide();
    $(".class3").show();
    $(".class4").hide();
    });
    $("#button4").click(function(){
    $(".class1").hide();
    $(".class2").hide();
    $(".class3").hide();
    $(".class4").show();
    })
    
});
```

Comment: i hope that what you want

Comment: i hope that what you want

Comment: Yes, the script works ONLY if I have divs with single class, I have been using it for a while.. What I meant was that now I have divs with multiple classes class="class1 class2" and what I want is that element is visible with button 1 and button 2 - however script chooses only the last class, making button 2 work as expected and button 1 does nothing - what I have done - I developed a workaround having separate classes for items with multiple classes - class="class1-class2" and having extra values like $(".class1-class2").show();

Comment: it's just a organization problem in your code
just focus and relax think about your code and what you want to do
and then you can do it by start organizing your divs and buttons

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

Hide all divs first and then show what you want!

Like this, divs can have multiple classes!

```
<button id="button1"></button>
<button id="button2"></button>
<button id="button3"></button>
<button id="button4"></button>

<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class3 class4"></div>
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
$("div").hide();
$(".class1").show();
});
$("#button1").click(function(){
$("div").hide();
$(".class2").show();
});
$("#button1").click(function(){
$("div").hide();
$(".class3").show();
});
$("#button1").click(function(){
$("div").hide();
$(".class4").show();
});
</script>
```

Thanks to everybody!